# Use regex in UFT PDF comparison

Tags: regex, qtp, hp-uft

In one of my UFT test cases, I need to verify a amount on a PDF file.

Sometimes the amount is "3000" and sometimes it is "3.000". And sometimes even "3 000"!

I would like to accept those 3 possibilities, knowing that this amount is stored in a datatable.

I tried something like "3.?000" (with regex check in the file checkpoint) but it's not matching any of the 3 solutions.

How would you do?

Comment: You need to check only the value of 3 thousand ?  Or any amount with `.` as thousand separator ?

Comment: I need to check the value of 3 thousands

Answer (score 0):

One of UFT's [idiosyncrasies when dealing with regexs](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/11/05/regular-expressions-in-uft/) is that it add implicit anchors at the beginning and ends of lines.
Try adding `.*` before and after the text you want to match - `.*\s3[., ]?000\s.*`.

Also verify that you've activated the regular expression flag for your line. I find the UI for File Content Checkpoints to be a bit unintuitive so you may have missed that.

[image: Screen shot of line with regex flag selected]

Comment: Hello Motti, it does not match 3000 and 3.000. So escaping the character would not change anything (also I didn't mention that there's also "3 000")

Comment: @Y-BCause I've updated my answer, also updated the regex to match `3000` `3,000` `3.000` and `3 000`

Comment: the data comes from a datatable, I guess this is why the regex doesn't match any of the possibilities